# Java Applet for File Download without Save-As

Tags: java, asp.net, coldfusion, applet, download

Back-story: We had an applet running on a Coldfusion (9) Page that looked like this:

```
    <APPLET CODE="com/infomentum/appletfile/FileDownload.class" ARCHIVE=FileDownload.jar NAME=FileDownload CODEBASE="/AppletFile/classes" WIDTH=2 HEIGHT=2 MAYSCRIPT>
<PARAM NAME="cabbase" VALUE="/AppletFile/classes/FileDownload.cab">
<PARAM NAME="directory" VALUE="<CFOUTPUT>#sFileDownloadPath#</CFOUTPUT>">
<PARAM NAME="noSaveAllTo" VALUE="true">
<PARAM NAME="noSaveAs" VALUE="true">
<PARAM NAME="noConfirm" VALUE="true">
```

Well this old applet was from a company that died a while back - and they stopped keeping their SSL Certs up to date. BAHHHH.

I dig around and find a java download applet called MyDownloader. Fine and dandy, but this and all the apps I've found allow the user pick the folder they want to save the file in. I'm all for this (seems fair), but because of the nature of this file delivery - management wants the file stored where the client sets their account up to go, not where some knucklehead accidentally saves it to.

NO SAVE AS. Seems like reasonable request, but I can't find a thing possibly due to fairly generic search terms (java download applet save as, etc). We're delivering this on a Coldfusion 9 Server at the moment.

Any and all insight is greatly welcomed.

We're also running asp.net 4.0 server, but still haven't seen much in the way on that front yet.

**EDIT:** Let's answer some of the questions - sorry for the slow response, I've been getting hammered (it's closing in on release time).

1. The original applet was signed but the company we bought the applet from is now defunk and not keeping the certs up to date. So right now, it's unsigned and will throw the SSL nag. The original applet would basically say "Save this file to c:\test? Confirm or Cancel" and then send the user to the success page.
2. Security risk: Definitely a risk to be able to save a file to client's local machine - it's something I've argued against - but these are logged in users paying for our services. Clearly if it was intended for malicious use, an applet like this could be bad.
3. @Dale Fraser: This isn't new functionality (our old applet did this) - but like I said, dead company not keeping the cert up to date. I will check out Air applet - though not at all familiar with it.

Comment: Hang on? It saves to a local file with path and contents specified in an applet tag? In html? Not signed? Anyone can put what they want there? Don't you think that might be a little bit of a security risk? / If the vendor can't keep a current code signing certificate (you don't mean [just] SSL, do you?), it probably isn't going to handle having a vulnerability found in its product very well. Having said that, you can sign together with a time stamp signing server which will allow the signature to be valid after the certificate has expired.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline - I agree, but is that even possible from a *non*-signed applet?  I thought security restrictions required it for actions like saving locally without prompting.

Comment: @Leight Well the applet is signed, but HTML pages are not. The assumption is that nobody signs code that does dodgy stuff, like trusting unsigned code/scripts/data/config.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline - Okay, gotcha.

Comment: I editted the OP with some more info, thnx guys.

Answer (score 1):

If you can find an app that does this, it will need to be a signed application with local trusted rights.

I think a better option may be to wrap your application in a container such as an Air app that you can sign and have more flexibility in what your users can do.

A web browser can only do so much and, what your asking is really a bit too much.

Comment: Well most signed controls (applet, activex,...) should be capable of doing this. So it is certainly possible from a technical standpoint. It think it is more a question of whether they can do it safely, and whether they want to roll their own. That said, I agree they probably want to look into moving away from applets if possible.

Comment: Curious as to why you guys think moving away from signed applets is wise? Clearly if we had something else, we wouldn't be stuck w/ an applet that has a dead cert - but is there another reason?